# Differential equation for a list with parameter dependent function

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am having a differential equation:

```
y' = (1 - y) - f[y, mu] y;
```

f is a hysteretic function that depends on y and on the derivative of y:

```
f[y_, mu_] := -1/(1 + Exp[(Abs[y] - mu)/k]) + 1;
mu[n_] := mu[n] = 0.5 + 0.1 Sign[y[n] - y[n - 1]];
```

For y being a scalar, I can solve the equation numerically:

```
x[0] = 0.0; y[0] = 0; y[1] = 0.1; x[n] = 2; h = .01;
x[n_] := x[n] = x[0] + n h;

y[n_] := Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4},
   k1 = h (f[x[n - 1], y[n - 1], mu[n - 1]]);
   k2 = h (f[x[n - 1] + h/2, y[n - 1] + k1/2, mu[n - 1]]);
   k3 = h (f[x[n - 1] + h/2, y[n - 1] + k2/2, mu[n - 1]]);
   k4 = h (f[x[n - 1] + h, y[n - 1] + k3, mu[n - 1]]);
   y[n] = y[n - 1] + (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)/6];
```

However, I need to solve the equation for a vector y with y[0]={0,0}. How can I expand Runge - Kutta for a list and still include the hysteretic function?

Comment: I love that you made your own RK4 algorithm, it's so much more fun than using the `ExplicitRungeKutta` method for `NDSolve`.  But here, I don't see why you should have any problem using a list for `y`.  If you take your `f` function and give it a list for the `y` argument, and a list for the `mu` argument, it returns a list, since both `Exp` and `Abs` thread over lists.

Comment: But I do see a problem with the code in that you are always passing 3 arguments to `f`, when you have `f` defined as taking only 2 arguments.  Also, `k` is undefined

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what value of `k` you are using, so in the code below I set it to 0.1.  Also, fixed the RK4 code so that it works, but now it's pretty slow.

```
(* set k to your value for k *)
k = .1;
f[y_, mu_] := -1/(1 + Exp[(Abs[y] - mu)/k]) + 1;
mu[n_] := mu[n] = 0.5 + 0.1 Sign[y[n] - y[n - 1]]; x[0] = 0.0; 
y[0] = 0; y[1] = 0.1; x[n] = 2; h = .01;
x[n_] := x[n] = 
  x[0] + n h;(*Why do you have x defined? Neither f nor mu depend on \
x*)

y[n_] := Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4},
  k1 = h (f[y[n - 1], mu[n - 1]]);
  k2 = h (f[y[n - 1] + k1/2, mu[n - 1]]);
  k3 = h (f[y[n - 1] + k2/2, mu[n - 1]]);
  k4 = h (f[y[n - 1] + k3, mu[n - 1]]);
  y[n - 1] + (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)/6];

Do[
 Print[AbsoluteTiming@y[n]]
 , {n, 1, 10}]

(*
{2.*10^-6,0.1}
{0.000128,0.100067}
{0.000468,0.100134}
{0.00234,0.100201}
{0.010894,0.100268}
{0.038722,0.100335}
{0.145408,0.100402}
{0.70548,0.10047}
{3.46992,0.100537}
{17.5871,0.100604}
*)
```

The time to compute the next `y` value is increasing exponentially.  The answer here is to make `y` a function of `yin`:

```
k = .1;
f[y_, mu_] := -1/(1 + Exp[(Abs[y] - mu)/k]) + 1;
ycomp = Compile[{{yin, _Real}, {muin, _Real}, {step, _Real}},
  Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4, yout, muout},
   k1 = step (f[yin, muin]);
   k2 = step (f[yin + k1/2, muin]);
   k3 = step (f[yin + k2/2, muin]);
   k4 = step (f[yin + k3, muin]);
   yout = yin + (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)/6;
   muout = 0.5 + 0.1 Sign[yout - yin];
   {yout, muout}]]
```

Now you get the exact same values for `y` in less than a millisecond.

```
{yc, muc} = {0.1, 0.6};
AbsoluteTiming@Table[{yc, muc} = ycomp[yc, muc, .01]; yc, {10}]
(* {0.000194, {0.100067, 0.100134, 0.100201, 0.100268, 0.100335,
   0.100402, 0.10047, 0.100537, 0.100604, 0.100672}} *)
```

So now, what if `y` were a list?  Just modify the `Compile` code a little bit,

```
k = .1;
f[y_, mu_] := -1/(1 + Exp[(Abs[y] - mu)/k]) + 1;
ycomp = Compile[{{yin, _Real, 1}, {muin, _Real, 1}, {step, _Real}},
  Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4, yout, muout},
   k1 = step (f[yin, muin]);
   k2 = step (f[yin + k1/2, muin]);
   k3 = step (f[yin + k2/2, muin]);
   k4 = step (f[yin + k3, muin]);
   yout = yin + (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)/6;
   muout = 0.5 + 0.1 Sign[yout - yin];
   {yout, muout}]]
```

Now all you have to do is supply the initial `yc` and `muc` as lists of any length and all is good.

```
yc = {0.1, 0.11};
muc = {0.6, 0.66};
AbsoluteTiming@Table[{yc, muc} = ycomp[yc, muc, .01]; yc, {10}]
(* {0.000895, {{0.100067, 0.110041}, {0.100134, 
   0.110115}, {0.100201, 0.110189}, {0.100268, 0.110263}, {0.100335, 
   0.110337}, {0.100402, 0.110411}, {0.10047, 0.110485}, {0.100537, 
   0.11056}, {0.100604, 0.110634}, {0.100672, 0.110708}}} *)
```

Comment: thank you very much. The code works very well.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.  If that solves the problem, go ahead and [mark it as solved](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so it doesn't stay in the "Unanswered questions" queue.